# Basis of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[n]7)$ over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I have the field extension $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[n]7)/\mathbb Q$ for $n\ge2$. I need to find the basis for this field extension but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: To start, do you know the degree of the extension? Can you start with $\sqrt[n]7$ and work from there?

Comment: The degree of the extension is $n$ since the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[n]7$ in $\Bbb Q$ is $X^n-7$

Comment: So how many basis vectors do you need to construct?

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$\dim_{\Bbb Q}\Bbb Q(\sqrt[n]7)=n$$

$$\{1,7^{1/n},7^{2/n},\ldots,7^{(n-1)/n}\}\;\;\text{is a $\;\Bbb Q\,$-linearly independent set}$$